# How to send selected term from drop boxes in tkinter to excel sheet?

Tags: excel, tkinter, pycharm

I working on a project and I'm using Pycharm tkinter and excel as my database. My question is how can I use drop boxes in tkinter and send the selected term to my excel? for example, my drop down box would the options to select from Drivers License, Passport, and ID, and after the rest of the entry boxes are filled out, the option selected from the drop down box be sent to the excel. I Attached a screen shot of what my current code for adding entry boxes to excel look like(It works for entry boxes). I'm using openpyxl to send the information to my excel if that helps. I apologize in advance for the format of this question.

```
     worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=1).value = FirstNameBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=2).value = LastNameBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=3).value = AddressBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=4).value = CityBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=5).value = StateBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=6).value = ZipCodeBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=7).value = NumberBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=8).value = EmailBox.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=9).value = NumKids.get()
    # Child 1
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=10).value = ChildFirstBox1.get() + " " + ChildLastBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=11).value = AgeBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=12).value = ShirtBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=13).value = PantsBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=14).value = ShoeBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=15).value = GenBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=16).value = DOBBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=17).value = WishBox1.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=18).value = WishBox2.get()
    worksheet.cell(row=current_row + 1, column=19).value = WishBox3.get()
```

[Excel submission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5IsH.png)

Comment: No screenshots of code. Please [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: Not Sure... Try this `mydropdown.get(mydropdown.curselection())`?